# Google maps setting different z-index based on Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, z-index

I have a Google map where I am dropping markers based on events, this happens periodically and after 8 hours a marker is removed. Events are real time and their is no guarantee which will appear when, on an average in period of 24 hours number of markers dropped will be somewhere between 5000 to 10000. For sake of this question lets assume I have below markers:

1. [image: Blue headphone] Blueheadphone marker (zindex must be set in way that it shows on top of any other icon no matter when other icons appear on the map) - **constant priority 5**
2. [image: Blue marker with arrow]- Blue marker with arrow (zindex should be such that it appears on top of others except Blueheadphone marker) - **constant priority 4**
3. [image: Blue marker] - Blue marker - **constant priority 3**
4. [image: Orange marker] - Orange Marker - **constant priority 2**
5. [image: Green marker] - Green Marker - **constant priority 1**

So to give you complete picture it may look like as below:

[image: Sample Image]

When I am adding them in Google Maps I am setting zindex like this:

```
zindex = intZIndex++ * constantprioirty 
//where intZIndex is int variable initialized with value 1.
```

Now obviously this doesn't work well because say first [image: Blue headphone] was dropped then it's zindex would be set to `1*5 = 5` and now when the say 20th marker is dropped and lets assume it is [image: Orange marker] and it is in same / overlapping location, its zindex would be `20*2 = 40` which obviously is greater than 5 so [image: Blue headphone] will go behind [image: Orange marker].

Another thing that I can probably try is to assign Prime numbers as priority and then do Priority<sup>(index++)</sup> but I don't think this will always work.

I was thinking if I can some how map them in two dimensions like shown below then using x and y, then I can probably get a unique number in a way that any number generated for [image: Orange marker] will never be bigger than any number generated for [image: Blue headphone]

[image: Example]

But I am not sure how this can be done. So if you have any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm basing this response on the assumption that you have provided a priority level and a time stamp to your multidimensional **`events []`** array in which you can implement the **`sort()`** method of the **`array()`** object.

The below code blocks are predicated on an example from this [Google MAP API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex).

**Assumed *`events[]`* array:**

```
var events = [
  ['Faneuil Hall, Boston MA', 4, 42.33095, -71.10963, 'January 1, 2016 03:30:00', 3],
  ['Boston Common, Boston MA', 5, 42.35500, -71.06556, 'February 20, 2016 02:23:00', 5],
  ['The Paul Revere House, Boston MA', 5, 42.3637351, -71.0558839, 'June 20, 2016 02:24:00', 4],
  ['Fenway Park, Boston MA', 3, 42.3466803, -71.0994065, 'March 8, 2016 01:20:00', 2],
  ['Beacon Hill, Boston MA', 2, 42.3583059, -71.0711146, 'April 19, 2016 02:20:00', 1]
];
```

Now you will invoke the function expression of the `sort()` method to the priority column (index 1) and then by the timestamp column (index 4).  I'm including both a circumlocutory and paired down version of the code for a better understanding of the structure.  Sometimes, ternary operators can be a bit confusing for readers as opposed to authors:

***`sort()`* method - Verbose:**

```
events.sort(function (a, b) {
    var date1, date2, priority1, priority2;

    date1 = new Date(a[4]).getTime();
    date2 = new Date(b[4]).getTime();

    priority = a[1];
    priority = b[1];

    if (priority1 < priority2) {
        return 1;
    } else if (priority1 > priority2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (date1 < date2) {
        return 1;
    } else if (date1 > date2) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

***`sort()`* method - Minified (Use of ternary operators):**

```
events.sort(function(a, b) {
  var date1, date2, priority1, priority2;

  return priority1 = a[1],
         priority2 = b[1],
         date1 = new Date(a[4]).getTime(),
         date2 = new Date(b[4]).getTime(),

         priority1 < priority2 ? 1 : priority1 > priority2 ? -1 : date1 < date2 ? 1 : date1 > date2 ? -1 : 0;
});
```

With the array now arranged from the highest priority and most recent date, you can decrement the z-index with the following line of code injected into a **`for()`** loop.

```
events[i][5] = events.length - [i];
```

The following **code snippet** shows a working example.  I'm also including a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sleonard947/g2x3fmo8/11/) to illustrate how the above code works.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 42.33196, lng: -71.020173}
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}

var events = [
  ['Faneuil Hall, Boston MA', 4, 42.33095, -71.10963, 'January 1, 2016 03:30:00', 3],
  ['Boston Common, Boston MA', 5, 42.35500, -71.06556, 'February 20, 2016 02:23:00', 5],
  ['The Paul Revere House, Boston MA', 5, 42.3637351, -71.0558839, 'June 20, 2016 02:24:00', 4],
  ['Fenway Park, Boston MA', 3, 42.3466803, -71.0994065, 'March 8, 2016 01:20:00', 2],
  ['Beacon Hill, Boston MA', 2, 42.3583059, -71.0711146, 'April 19, 2016 02:20:00', 1]
];

events.sort(function (a, b) {
  var date1, date2, priority1, priority2;

  date1 = new Date(a[4]).getTime();
  date2 = new Date(b[4]).getTime();
  priority1 = a[1];
  priority2 = b[1];

  if (priority1 < priority2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (priority1 > priority2) {
    return -1;
  } else if (date1 < date2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (date1 > date2) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});

function setMarkers(map) {
  var image = {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
      
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    events[i][5] = events.length - [i];
    var beach = events[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[2], lng: beach[3]},
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[5],
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #C1F0C1;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#pac-input {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDVcdnzK1fFrT1TXnWt1EPVCQvC2vg_AZY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 from my side for being so thorough. As mentioned in the question markers are added periodically (lets say whenever event occurs a trigger from the server will be generated and new markers will be fetched from DB) wouldn't  generating z-Index from this code `events[i][5] = events.length - [i];` overwrite zindexes for old markers which are already placed on the map? I have updated your [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2x3fmo8/13/) do demo events that occur periodically.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  For clarity, you are looking to sort by priority and current date, correct?

Comment: Upto some extent, The event markers will keep appearing so for example say when first time map was loaded it will have 10 markers and after say five minutes 20 more events (like people downloading software or people commenting on website and so on) occurred at this point of time this new 20 markers will be added to the map (in addition of 10 markers which are already present). Both of your example are great start but it assumes that once the markers are placed the job is done. In reality markers will keep appearing non stop based on external data.

Comment: If you're pulling data from an external source, then the only thing that will change is the *multidimensional events array* and its *length() property*.  This *array* stores all of your data.  The code structure will stay the same, as it is based on the *events.length() property*.  For example, lets say your data pulled two additional **events** to the *array*, instead of having 5 locations you now have 7.  Here is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sleonard947/g2x3fmo8/14/) illustrating no change in the code other than the increase in the **events** *arrays* length.

Comment: Keep in mind, the illustrated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sleonard947/g2x3fmo8/14/) is used to show the data references being updated with the ***sort()** method*.  The actual working model in the code snippet will demonstrate its effectiveness.